# What viewController to use with Facebook Graph API /{user-id}/feed (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a application that have to retrieve the newsfeed of a festivals facebookpage.
I have already implemented the login button and added the following code given by facebook/dev, in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"with": @"location",
                         };
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/137893439617162/feed"
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
}];
```

However nothing is showing. I have tried looking for answer but none seems to give me any answers to my problem.

Do i need to use a specific ViewController or is it something else that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the use of the FG API for iOS SDK and for better guidance we need a bit more information about your project.

1. Read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) carefully. 
   The FG and the iOS SDK is constantly updating but the basic features are the same.
2. As you will see in the link above, the `... initWithGraphPath:@"/137893439617162/feed" ...` is not an legal use of FG.
3. Make sure you got the right permissions for you FB API Token. As I read your question and as I remember the documents you need a permission called `read_stream`
4. If your app is an news app for this festival, you should try to find out if this festival have an RSS news feed. That is a much easier way to collect the latest news. A lot of big festivals have one and if they do you should find a tutorial for a iOS RSS-Reader. There are tons of these.
5. Good luck :-)